# About turtlebot_2dnav

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, robotwebtools, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to implement the backend for one web application that use the `NAV2DJS` from Robot web tools, I made a launch file in order to have all the nodes required, but it gives me this error:

> [ WARN] [1427214700.876816371]:
> Waiting on transform from
> base_footprint to map to become
> available before running costmap, tf
> error:

In order to try only this part `turtlebot_2dnav` (having on mind the nodes already used by the webpage), this is the order of launching nodes

```
$ roscore
$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
$ roslaunch openni_camera openni.launch
$ roslaunch control turtlebot_2dnav.launch
```

Where turtlebot_2dnav.launch file is:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="image" default="/camera/depth/image_raw"/>
  <node name="depthimage_to_laserscan" pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" args="$(arg image)"/>

  <!-- Map server -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="map_file" default="/home/robot/Desktop/gamma/map_sample/office.yaml"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)"/>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml">
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>

</launch>
```

The actual graph of this part is:

[Graph](http://postimg.org/image/tt6c9onnl/)

What could be the problem?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205792/about-turtlebot_2dnav/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-03-25**:
please, can you post your tf tree also? `rosrun tf view_frames`

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-25**:
you can take a look here: [Frames](http://pdfsr.com/pdf/frames.pdf) I cannot post images because I don't have enough karma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I make a little package that satisfy this requirement, for further info: [turtlebot_2dnav](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_2dnav#preview).

---

Originally posted by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) with karma: 82 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0